# Multiple Integral Substitution Error

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I just started learning about the substitution rule for multiple integrals and I decided to give myself an example problem:

> Calculate $\iint_R{(x^2 + y^2)dA}$ with $R = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R} \ |\ 0
> \le x + 2y \le 2 \land 0 \le x - y \le 1\}$

To calculate this, I decided to substitute $x = \frac{1}{3}(u+2v)$ and $y = \frac{1}{3}(u-v)$, (which is the same as $u = x + 2y$ and $v = x - y$). Under this substitution, the region of integral becomes $S = \{(u, v) \in \Bbb{R} \ |\ 0 \le u \le 2 \land 0 \le v \le 1\}$, which we can integrate directly. Now our integral is
$$
\begin{align}
\iint_R{(x^2+y^2)dA} & = \int_0^1\int_0^2{\left[\frac{1}{9}(u+2v)^2 + \frac{1}{9}(u-v)^2\right]\left|\frac{\partial{(x, y)}}{\partial{(u, v)}}\right|dudv} \\
& = -\frac{1}{27}\int_0^1\int_0^2{\left[(u+2v)^2 + (u-v)^2\right]dudv}.
\end{align}
$$
Because $\left|\frac{\partial{(x, y)}}{\partial{(u, v)}}\right| = -\frac{1}{3}$.

Here is when I run into a problem. The original integrand is positive everywhere, so the volume is positive as well. But the transformed integrand is positive everywhere as well, so when multiplied by a negative constant it must mean that the volume is negative. How can the volume be both positive and negative at the same time? Where was my error?

Comment: A negative sign says that your substitution reversed the orientation of the region $R$. This is a 2-dimensional analogue of what you have seen in univariate case, where you need to swap the boundaries, when you make a substitution with a negative derivative, i.e. use a decreasing function. If left unfixed that will reverse the sign. The remedy is easy: negate the result. BTW Well spotted! If only all the students were equally observant!

Comment: You should be taking $\left |-\dfrac1 3\right|$. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856654/why-absolute-values-of-jacobians-in-change-of-variables-for-multiple-integrals-b).

Comment: Oh, I thought the vertical lines around the jacobian meant you take the determinant of it, not the *absolute value* of the determinant. Thanks guys for pointing that out!

Comment: Great question.

Comment: @user3002473 And it can be determinant also. This depends on the text.