# Propose a change of variables to simplify the double integral of (y-2x)^2(x+y)^2dydx

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{2x-2}^{2x+2}\ (y-2x)^2\ (x+y)^2\ dy\ dx$$

I began by proposing $u=y-2x$ and $v=x+y$ and then solving each for $x$ and $y$ then computing the Jacobian which came out to be $-1/3$.

The last part of the problem says to reformulate the integral in terms of the new variables and solve, so I used the given bounds for integration and the change of variable I proposed. But then I got lost in what I was doing while computing the value.

Am I on the right track? All the examples give the change of variable, so I do not understand how to come up with that. Any help would be great.

Comment: Your suggestion is quite reasonable.  Without seeing your work, we can't tell where you got lost.  If you expand the squares and multiply you will get a polynomial in $x,y$ which is not hard to integrate.  This will give you something to check your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but be careful about the Jacobian. It looks like if you proceed with the $u,v$ you chose and $J=-1/3$, then may wind up with a negative answer if not careful. Correct magnitude, wrong sign. Why? [This is related to properties of the Jacobian. When negative, it will give you a negatively oriented region. This article spells it out in detail. In practice, just take the absolute value of J when necessary.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856654/why-absolute-values-of-jacobians-in-change-of-variables-for-multiple-integrals-b). Everything else you wrote looks good. Let's compute the integral out using your $u$ and $v$ but using the new bounds, defined in terms of $u$ and $v$.

$$u=y-2x\ \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ \ v=x+y$$

implies

$$x=\frac{v-u}{3}\ \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ \ y=\frac{u+2v}{3}.$$

This gives 
$$J = = \frac{1}{9}det\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}=-\frac{1}{3}.$$
$$|J| = \frac{1}{3}$$

The original bounds for $y$ are $y=2x-2$ to $y=2x+2$. Substituting the above equations gives new bounds $v=u-3$ and $v=u+3$. Similarly for $x=-1$ to $x=1$, we get $u=-2$ to $u=2$.

Putting everything together, and moving the constant Jacobian to the front, we get

$$\frac{1}{3}\int_{-2}^2\int_{u-3}^{u+3}\ u^2 v^2 dv\ du$$

$$\frac{1}{9}\int_{-2}^2\ u^2 \{(u+3)^3 - (u-3)^3\}\ du$$

This doesn't look pretty, but think about Pascal's triangle for a bit, and you'll see that half of the terms inside the braces cancel, while the other half sum together, resulting in

$$\frac{2}{9}\int_{-2}^2\ u^2 (9u^2+27)\ du$$

$$2\int_{-2}^2\ u^4+3u^2\ du$$

This is an even integral, so

$$4\int_{0}^2\ u^4+3u^2\ du$$

$$4\left( \frac{u^5}{5}+u^3 \right)\bigg|_0^2$$

$$-4\left( \frac{32}{5}+8 \right) = 57.6$$

[This matches Wolfram's output.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28y-2x%29%5E2%28x%2By%29%5E2dydx%2C%20%20y%3D%282x-2%29%20to%20%282x%2B2%29%2C%20x%3D-1%20to%201)