# Is the product of two independent random distributions commutative?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Based on the formula in:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution

It seems that Z = XY = YX. However, if X is a bounded uniform distribution, one could have either

$f_Y(z/x)$ or $f_Y(z)$, producing two different values for the Z integral

I am missing something?

Comment: The two integrals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(z/x) \frac{1}{|x|} \, dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y) f_X(z/y) \frac{1}{|y|} \, dy$ will be the same.

Comment: What does $f_Y(z \mid x)$ mean and same question for $f_Y(z)$?

Comment: Also... use \mid for the "given" condition in probability, it looks better.

Comment: @WillM, they’re not intended to be conditionals—actual division.

Comment: +1 @angryavian, correct.

Comment: Oh, okay. In that case you can use \frac{}{}  which is a tiny fraction, perhaps clearer.

Comment: @angryavian, I see, I was able to get the second integral by a change of variables y=z/x, except for a -ve sign (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856654/why-absolute-values-of-jacobians-in-change-of-variables-for-multiple-integrals-b)

Comment: That is why we take the absolute determinant for the Jacobian transition matrix.

Comment: @Graham Kemp I don't think you do in 1D: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856654/why-absolute-values-of-jacobians-in-change-of-variables-for-multiple-integrals-b