# Convolution with the "wrong" sign

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $u\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, $\eta\in C([-1, 1]^n, [0, 1])$ and, given $\epsilon>0$ consider the mollifier $\eta_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^{-n} \eta(x/\epsilon)$.

Define $u_\epsilon = u\ast \eta_\epsilon$, where $\ast$ denote the convolution [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#:~:text=The%20term%20convolution%20refers%20to,the%20y%2Daxis%20and%20shifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#:%7E:text=The%20term%20convolution%20refers%20to,the%20y%2Daxis%20and%20shifted).

Let $s\in )0, 1)$. For an exercise, I am calculating $\frac{(u_\epsilon(x)-u_\epsilon(y))}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}$ which according to me is
$$\frac{(u_\epsilon(x)-u_\epsilon(y))}{|x-y|^{n+2s}} =\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{(u(x-z) +u(y-z)) \eta_\epsilon(z)}{|x-y|^{n+2s}} dz.$$

Reading the solution proposed by the lecturer, the idea to solve the exercise is the same as mine, but when he computes the convolution writes
$$\frac{(u_\epsilon(x)-u_\epsilon(y))}{|x-y|^{n+2s}} =\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{(u(x+z) +u(y+z)) \eta_\epsilon(z)}{|x-y|^{n+2s}} dz.$$

Are the two definitions equivalent?
I do not understand why he uses the "+" sign, I have tried with a change of variables and other tricks, but it does not work, unless one assume any symmetry on $\eta_\epsilon$.

Anyone please help me to understand why the latter inequality holds? How to get from $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{(u(x-z) +u(y-z)) \eta_\epsilon(z)}{|x-y|^{n+2s}} dz$ to $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{(u(x+z) +u(y+z)) \eta_\epsilon(z)}{|x-y|^{n+2s}} dz$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, it is fine to assume the mollifier is a radial function, so $\eta(z) = \eta(-z)$. I can't see why it wouldn't be fine to assume so here. Otherwise, like you said, the two integrals generally won't be the same, and I would use the convention you originally made, rather than the one with "$+$" signs.

Comment: Alex Ortiz, when you change variables $-z\mapsto z$, you also get $-dz$. Hence, should not the mollifier be odd?

Comment: @Physicsuser: In R^n, you should check that the Lebesgue measure is invariant under reflections $z\mapsto -z$. So $dz$ is left unchanged. You can read more here about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856654/why-absolute-values-of-jacobians-in-change-of-variables-for-multiple-integrals-b

Comment: @Physicsuser: Another comment, if the mollifier were odd, then $\int \eta = 0$. Typically we require of a mollifier that $\int \eta = 1$. I would recommend you check Stein and Shakarchi's book "Real Analysis," or else any other introductory textbook on measure theory for the essentials of Lebesgue integration, and how it transforms with respect to linear changes of variable.